# Java Spring Application, after HTTP request method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I a writing a Java Spring Microservice.  My controller uses @PostMapping

After a HTTP request to my controller completes I would like to automatically call a cleanup method.  Is this possible?

Reason is my app can throw from different places and if I had one single method that gets called after the request completes then I can just write my cleanup routine in one place and not worry about leaving out cleanup code from new flows in the service.

Comment: Have you thought about using Spring AOP? Specifically the after advice in your case. Would that help?

Comment: What you mean by throw ? If you mean that your app may throw exception from different place's then it's possible to implement custom ErrorHandler in which you can perform your cleanup and also modify response for certain exception. Also it would be good to know if you want to cleanup only for controller's you specify (in that case use AOP) or for any HTTP request (in that case implement own filter which will perform your functionality on each response).

Comment: Why you don’t call it directly inside your PostMapping annotated method?

Comment: Spring AOP or interceptor can be used depending upon your use case.

Comment: can you provide an example what kind of cleanup you want to do? Does it invoke for every controller endpoints and after the request completes or as part of request lifecycle (which can be done using filters)?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class which implements `HandlerInterceptor` and then over-ride `postHandle` or `afterCompletion`